# Polymner ajax-core json response

Tags: json, polymer

Is there a way for core-ajax to automatically format the response of the on-core-error method to json.

My code look as follow:

```
<link href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html" rel="import" />
<link href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import" />
<link href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html" rel="import" />
<link href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import"/>
<link href="app-globals.html" rel="import" />

<polymer-element name="app-un-authenticated">
    <template>
        <core-ajax id="ajax" method="POST" url="someurl" headers='{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }' on-core-response="{{handleReponse}}" on-core-error="{{handleError}}" handleAs="json"></core-ajax>
        <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>        
        <div vertical layout center center-justified style="height: 100vh;">
            <paper-input-decorator label="Username" floatinglabel>
                <input is="core-input" value="{{username}}" />
            </paper-input-decorator>
            <paper-input-decorator label="Password" floatinglabel>
                <input is="core-input" type="password" value="{{password}}" />
            </paper-input-decorator>
            <paper-button on-click="{{buttonClick}}">Sign In</paper-button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('app-un-authenticated', {
            publish : {
                username: '',
                password: ''
            },

            buttonClick: function (event, detail, sender) {                
                var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password + "&client_id=some_id";                
                this.$.ajax.body = data;
                this.$.ajax.go();
            },

            handleReponse: function (event, detail, sender) {
                this.$.globals.authentication.token = detail.response.access_token;
                this.$.globals.authentication.expires = detail.response.expires_in;
                this.$.globals.authentication.isAuthorized = true;
            },

            handleError: function (event, detail, sender)
            {
                alert(detail.response.error + " " + detail.response.error_description);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The response is properly formatted when the on-core-response method is fired (i.e. no response error) but when the on-core-error method is fired the response is plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server returning the correct content type even when there is an error ?

Comment: No it didn't. Part of it was, but there was a error code before the json. Thanks.